# SVG: How to remove the offset from tspan for multiline text with text-anchor set to middle?

Tags: svg, text, tspan

I have some multi-line text and I am using `<text>` and `<tspan>` to handle this.  I want each line to be centered, so I am using in the main `<text>` tag `text-anchor="middle"`. However, even with `dx=0`, the entire block is still shifted by the total length text.

How can I do multi-lined `<tspan>` centered SVG text?

e.g.

```
<text text-anchor="middle" font-size="12px">
    This would normally be centered
    <tspan>
        this should be too.
    </tspan>
</text>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify the same x for the tspan as the text e.g.

```html
<svg>
<text x="100" y="30" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12px">
    This would normally be centered
    <tspan x="100" dy="30">
        this should be too.
    </tspan>
</text>
</svg>
```

or use a transform and set x="0" for the tspan...

```html
    <svg>
    <text transform="translate(100, 30)" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12px">
        This would normally be centered
        <tspan x="0" dy="30">
            this should be too.
        </tspan>
    </text>
    </svg>
```